# Manipulate panel does not print (or print to pdf) the same as it displays in a notebook

Tags: manipulate, pdf-format, printing, button, slider

Whenever I print (or print to pdf) a manipulate panel it never looks like the manipulate panel I have in the notebook on my display.  This is what the manipulate panel looks like on my display.

[image]

This is what the manipulate panel looks like when printed out.

[image]

Notice the buttons and slider look different.  I would like the printed out version to look like it does on my display.  I have tried messing with output styles and PrintingStyleEnvironment to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is what is generated by `Style[ Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, a}], {a, 1, 10}],
 ControlsRendering -> "Generic" ]` but I don't know how to fix "nonGeneric" style for "Printing" environment :?

Comment: @Kuba Good point! Yes, on my system (Win7 x64) the `Export`ed PDF file contains the `"Generic"` controls: `Export["test.pdf", {Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
  Style[Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}], ControlsRendering -> "Generic"]}]` ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zLCKd.png)). Nice thing about them is that they are in vectors, not raster!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov The solutions on your linked page works.  However the quality of the image is diminished enough to make me question whether I should settle for the different controls.  Thank you for your solution though.